# Why auto redirecting to another unwanted URL after redirecting to a wanted URL in Puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, web-crawler, puppeteer

I'm scraping the trending articles from [Medium](https://medium.com) using `Puppeteer`.

But, after going to the **targeted URL** (page of single article e.g. `https://royals.mlblogs.com/?source=home---------0---------------------54c56bca_541c_4664_80aa_ea1a69f93942-------7`) after 1-2 seconds it's auto redirecting to **wanted URL**: `https://royals.mlblogs.com/`

I don't know why this kind of behavior is happening. How to keep into the targeted URL?

Here is my code:

```
'use strict';

const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
    try {
        const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
            args: [`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/%s Safari/537.36`],
            headless: false,
            devtools: true,
            defaultViewport: {
                width: 1920,
                height: 1080
            }
        });
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        const initialTargetedURL = 'https://medium.com/';

        await page.setBypassCSP(true);
        await page.goto(initialTargetedURL);
        await page.waitForSelector('div[class="iw ix z"]')

        const trendingArticles = await page.$$('div[class="iw ix z"] div[class="an do"]');
        console.log(trendingArticles.length);

        for (let i = 0; i < trendingArticles.length; i++) {
            await page.goto(initialTargetedURL);
            await page.waitForSelector('div[class="iw ix z"]');
            const trendingArticles = await page.$$('div[class="iw ix z"] div[class="an do"]');
            const trendingArticle = trendingArticles[i];

            const link = await trendingArticle.$('div[class="an br ay"] > a');

            // redirect way 1
            const linkToVisit = await  page.evaluate(link => link.getAttribute('href'), link)
            console.log('linkToVisit', linkToVisit)
            await page.goto(linkToVisit);

            // redirect way 2
            // await link.click()

            await page.waitForSelector('div[class="n p"]')

            const article = await page.$('div[class="n p"]')
            console.log('Hi, there...', article)
        }

        // await browser.close();
    } catch (e) {
        if (e instanceof puppeteer.errors.TimeoutError) {
            console.log('Oppsss! Timeout.', e)
        } else {
            console.log('::Error::', e)
        }
    }
})();
```